# Strip all characters from column header before a :

Tags: python, pandas

I have column's named like this:

```
1:Arnston 2:Berg 3:Carlson 53:Brown
```

and I want to strip all the characters before and including `:`. I know I can rename the columns, but that would be pretty tedious since my numbers go up to 100.

My desired out put is:

Arnston Berg Carlson Brown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a frame looking something like this:

```
>>> df
   1:Arnston  2:Berg  3:Carlson  53:Brown
0          5       0          2         1
1          9       3          2         9
2          9       2          9         7
```

You can use the vectorized string operators to split each entry at the first colon and then take the second part:

```
>>> df.columns = df.columns.str.split(":", 1).str[1]
>>> df
   Arnston  Berg  Carlson  Brown
0        5     0        2      1
1        9     3        2      9
2        9     2        9      7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
columns = '1:Arnston 2:Berg 3:Carlson 53:Brown'.split()
print('Before: {!r}'.format(columns))

columns = [col.split(':')[1] for col in columns]
print('After: {!r}'.format(columns))
```

**Output**

```
Before: ['1:Arnston', '2:Berg', '3:Carlson', '53:Brown']
After: ['Arnston', 'Berg', 'Carlson', 'Brown']
```

Another way is with a regular expression using [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

columns = '1:Arnston 2:Berg 3:Carlson 53:Brown'.split()

pattern = re.compile(r'^.+:')
columns = [pattern.sub('', col) for col in columns]
print(columns)
```

**Output**

```
['Arnston', 'Berg', 'Carlson', 'Brown']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = '1:Arnston 2:Berg 3:Carlson 53:Brown'
s_minus_numbers = re.sub(r'\d+:', '', s)
```

Gets you

```
'Arnston Berg Carlson Brown'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution IMO is to use pandas' `str` attribute on the columns. This allows for the use of regular expressions without having to import `re`:

```
df.columns.str.extract(r'\d+:(.*)')
```

Where the regex means: select everything (`(.*)`) after one or more digits (`\d+`) and a colon (`:`).

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1:Arnston':[5,9,9],
  '2:Berg':[0,3,2],
  '3:Carlson':[2,2,9] ,
  '53:Brown':[1,9,7]})

[x.split(':')[1] for x in df.columns.factorize()[1]]
```

output:

```
['Arnston', 'Berg', 'Carlson', 'Brown']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and pass regex expression:

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]:
   1:Arnston    2:Berg  3:Carlson  53:Brown
0   1.340711  1.261500  -0.512704 -0.064384
1   0.462526 -0.358382   0.168122 -0.660446
2  -0.089622  0.656828  -0.838688 -0.046186
3   1.041807  0.775830  -0.436045  0.162221
4  -0.422146  0.775747   0.106112 -0.044917

In [51]: df.columns.str.replace('\d+[:]','')
Out[51]: Index(['Arnston', 'Berg', 'Carlson', 'Brown'], dtype='object')
```